# VS Code main window is blank in version 1.27.0

Tags: visual-studio-code

I was update Visual Studio Code from 1.26 to 1.27.0 and have error blank when open VS Code.
I was try some way to resolve this issue but it didn't working:

- Uninstall VS Code and reinstall version 1.27.0
- Setting the compatibility with windows 8 in VsCODE shortcut.
- Right-click on Shortcut and add --disable-gpu to Target: "C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe" --disable-gpu

[image]

[image]
Is there some way to fix this issue??

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was fix in version 1.27.1: https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_27